# double grep on tail -f gives no output

Tags: grep, io-redirection, output

If I follow a file somehow like this:

```
tail -f  /var/log/syslog|grep s
```

I see all lines containing an "s"

Why does this not give any output, if I grep it again to the same "s"?

```
tail -f  /var/log/syslog|grep s|grep s
```

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13858912/1601027)

Comment: That is a part of solution, but why does grep work without --line-buffered if there is only **one** grep?

Comment: Well, if you actually read Chin's answer, it points to [BashFAQ/009](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009) and there's your answer: _There is no problem if we simply run_ `tail -f logfile`, _because_ `tail -f` _never buffers its output. Nor is there a problem if we run_ `tail -f logfile | grep 'foo bar'` _interactively, because_ `grep` _does not buffer its output if its standard output is a terminal. However, if the output of_ `grep` _is being piped into something else it starts buffering to improve efficiency._

Comment: How many lines would grep buffer without --line-buffered?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Rubo77 mentioned, the issue is solved by adding the `--line-buffered` to the first grep command:

```
tail -f  /var/log/syslog|grep --line-buffered s|grep s
```

However, you then may ask, why isn't this needed for a single `grep` command?  The difference between the two is that in the following command:

```
tail -f  /var/log/syslog|grep s
```

`STDOUT` for grep is pointed to a terminal.  `grep` most likely writes to `STDOUT` via functions contained in the stdio library.  Per the documentation ([stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html)):

> Output streams that refer to terminal devices are always line buffered by default;

Thus, the underlying library calls are flushing the buffer after each line without any action on grep's part.

In this command:

```
tail -f  /var/log/syslog|grep --line-buffered s|grep s
```

`STDIO` is now going to a pipe rather than a terminal device and the library functions that grep is using to write to STDOUT fully buffers these writes rather than using line buffering.  When the `--line-buffered` flag is used, grep will call `fflush`, which will flush all of the buffered write.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `--line-buffered` to grep

```
tail -f  /var/log/syslog|grep --line-buffered s|grep s
```

Comment: So to answer why: If does work, but because outputing is expensive programs buffer the output until they have a lot to output, the program calls the flush routine, or the program ends. `--line-buffered` will cause grep to call flush after each line. When you are not following programs end so buffers are output. When there is only one grep after the tail … (can someone explain this?)