# bash grep in a tee

Tags: bash, grep, tee

I am trying to write a log file and output to a console at the same time The below works well. However I have a sleep timer and the logfile counts down each second and fills the log. The "Sleeping for..." is in stdout not in the stderr.

```
watch_dog > >(tee -a ${LOGFILE}) 2> >(tee -a ${LOGFILE} 2>&1)
```

I would like to add

```
grep -v "Sleeping for..."
```

The console should still dislpay everything.
The log file should omit any line that has  "Sleeping for..."
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Something like

```
watch_dog > >(grep -v "Sleeping for..." | tee -a ${LOGFILE}) 2> >(tee -a ${LOGFILE} 2>&1)
```

or

```
watch_dog 2>&1 | tee >( grep -v 'Sleeping for...' >${LOGFILE} )
```

However these don't work

Comment: Why, and how to work around it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164681/315749; also, what to do if the program you're using doesn't doesn't have options to configure buffering: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/315749